# Start and Stop Handlers in python3.7

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, python-3.7

An app engine application written in python2.7 has the following structure in app.yaml

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/push-handlers/.*
  script: main.app
  #login: admin
  secure: always

- url: /_ah/start
  script: start.app

- url: /_ah/stop
  script: stop.app
```

The start.py and stop.py is handled by /-ah/start and /_ah/stop respectiveley and they
contain respective methods when the appengine application is started and stopped to handle pubsub messages. for ex start.py contains this code

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/_ah/start', ReceiveStart)
], debug=True)
```

and this class to handle which contains default get method

```
class ReceiveStart(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    

    def get(self):
        last_end_time_str = ""
        try:
            # get the App Engine default bucket name to store a GCS file with last end_time
            project_id = app_identity.get_application_id()
```

Now if convert this application to **python3.7**(not yet tested) the app.yaml becomes

handlers:

```
- url: /_ah/push-handlers/.*
  script: auto
  #login: admin
  secure: always

- url: /_ah/start
  script: auto

- url: /_ah/stop
  script: auto
  
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```

Will this redirection take place as in the python2.7 when messages are sent and received to this app engine, Is the url correct for start.app and stop.app as the script is set to auto and not to start.app and stop.app will this work?

new to both python and app-engine, Help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

With AppEngine 2nd generation, the webserver is more agnostic of the platform and you can run the framework that you want with the library that you want.

In Python, Flask is commonly used for API. Django more for web app.

Anyway, now, your handler doesn't route the request to a specific script, but route the request to your webserver that have to handle the request.

The usage of `/_ah/start` and `/__ah/stop` is the same but you have to define these routes in your webserver. Here an example in flask

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/_ah/start')
def start():
    print("start called")
    return "",200

@app.route('/_ah/stop')
def stop():
    print("stop called")
    return "",200
```

Comment: Thanks, should these methods @app.route('/_ah/start') be defined in the main.py file , when you mean webserver, and start.py and stop.py is not necessary?

Comment: I had defined the method like this with a class and inside that a method. class 
 class ReceiveStart(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     def get(self):, should this be replaced by something like without the need for class?    
    @app.route('/_ah/start')                                                                                              
     def get(self)

Comment: I never used classes with Flask. I think you can, but you should have to use a [blueprint](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/)